# Magento 2 include wp-load.php from WordPress?

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, wordpress

I've got a WordPress website with Magento in a sub-folder for the store functionality

I'm trying to include `wp-load.php` from WordPress into Magento so that I have access to use some of the WordPress functions which I would like to use. However I receive the following error since both WordPress and Magento have a `__()` function.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in /products/app/functions.php:14) in /wp-includes/l10n.php on line 207
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: You cannot do this. Use a WordPress extension on your Magento shop or make a Magento module yourself containing the functionalities you want to use from WordPress.

Comment: Hi heady12! did you find the solution. Because I am facing the same?

Comment: @SanchitGupta I decided against loading the wp-load.php and instead utilised the WordPress API to pass the data over to Magento.

Comment: Thank you @heady12! Now I am also following this approach.